# Code responding in JavaScript for huge calculations

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

The quote from the "Understanding ECMASCript 6" book:

> JavaScript engines are built on the concept of a single-threaded event loop.
>   Single-threaded means that only one piece of code is executed at a time.
>   ...
>   JavaScript engines can execute only one piece of code at a time, so
>   they need to keep track of code that is meant to run. That code is
>   kept in a job queue. Whenever a piece of code is ready to be executed,
>   it is added to the job queue. When the JavaScript engine is finished
>   executing code, the event loop executes the next job in the queue. The
>   event loop is a process inside the JavaScript engine that monitors
>   code execution and manages the job queue. Keep in mind that as a
>   queue, job execution runs from the first job in the queue to the last.

Does it mean if the next piece of code in the job queue takes a lot of time then web application will be not responding til that code will be finished? What is size of "piece of code" ? Is it function body or code block (i.e. code inside of {}  brackets)? Function body contains other function calling (this is the rabbit hole...). It confuses me.

For example, it can be huge code of the function which is used in initializing of the Promise instance, or huge code in the `.then((resolve,reject)=> {...}`:

```
// ...
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Here is long work
    // ...
});

// ...

p.then(() => {
    // Or long work is here
    // ...
});
```

Comment: You can use a `setTimeout(() => { /* your big calculation here */ }, 0);` to run it in parallel. Or use WebWorkers.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed, `setTimeout(() => { /* your big calculation here */ }, 0);` doesn't work parallel as I know. It creates a new job in the job queue. So, it will not help. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, there's no way in JS to use more than one thread unless you use WebWorkers. But using `setTimeout()` will not block your web page from responding while the heavy calculations happen.

Comment: But what will happen when it is time to execute this code  as a next job of the  job queue?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I stand corrected. 

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed, I do not argue. I try to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186218/discussion-between-andrey-bushman-and-faizuddin-mohammed).

Comment: If you need long running computations, this is better offloaded to webworkers, which does not block the main thread. Another option might be to chunk up your heavy calculation to allow other commands to be interleaved on the jobqueue.

Comment: Is the calculation huge enough to do it on the server instead?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, but JavaScript can be used on server (Node.js). I.e. frontend and backend both use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean if the next piece of code in the job queue takes a lot of
>   time then web application will be not responding til that code will be
>   finished?

Basically yes, the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) matters a lot when you're running the code in the Event Loop. In nodejs for example, is not recommended to use the synchronous version of the encryption api, i.e:

- `crypto.randomBytes (synchronous version)`
- `crypto.randomFillSync`
- `crypto.pbkdf2Sync`

since they involve expensive computation.

> What is size of "piece of code" ? Is it function body or code block (i.e. code inside of {} brackets)?

From your quote, "piece of code" I think it just refers to a statement, therefore a single thread can only execute ONE statement at a time, so there is no parallel execution happening, which you can only achieve with multiple threads.

Side note: rather than "size of piece of code" it's more important [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). 
A rather large "size of piece of code" could run in constant time O(1), whilst a smaller snippet could take exponential time.

More info [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/), particularly for Google V8 Engine.

**TL;DR**: Computational complexity matters, especially in single threaded engines. For long running computations, either use web workers in the browser or a child process if using node.

Answer (score 0):

[Concurrency-modeil and javascript_eventloops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Well, my take is to do these massive huge operations in background and render the web application first(the chunks of code it executes to show up the application).

Go through this topic: [Run to completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion)

Hope this answers your question..

Answer (score -1):

you can setInterval for each function to reduce the time for executing the script.

Comment: Maybe you meant `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` function?

Comment: You probably mean ‘setTimeout’, but that doesn’t reduce execution time for a script, it merely schedules execution to x milliseconds (whatever x you choose) plus the time it takes to clear the entire jobqueue

Comment: you will choose recursive method it will be reduce the execution time.